# service_identity installed but not working

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, websocket, autobahn

under root I ran `pip3 install service_identity` and `easy_install service_identity`

both installed successfully yet the warning still shows and clients can't connect.
They close before handshake.

***Full Warning***

> :0: UserWarning: You do not have a working installation of the service_identity >module: 'No module named 'cryptography.x509''.  Please install it from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/service_identity and make sure all of its >dependencies are satisfied.  Without the service_identity module, Twisted can >perform only rudimentary TLS client hostname verification.  Many valid >certificate/hostname mappings may be rejected.

Comment: Need more detail of the warning.

Comment: added warning to details

Answer (score 6):

Fixed with the following,

`pip3 install cryptography`

`pip3 install cffi --upgrade`

`pip3 install service_identity --upgrade`

`pip3 install pyopenssl --upgrade`

Comment: Thanks! In my case the last line was unnecessary because pyopenssl was updated with cryptography.

Comment: I ran into errors trying to upgrade cffi and service_identity. Solved by following https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/31741#issuecomment-337745346